# Hightlight the ListView row when a contained UI element of row is touched

Tags: android, events, listview, onclick, highlighting

I want to enable the orange highlight that occurs when touching a listView row.

If the onclick event was generated from the row itself, I can adjust the hightlight by setting the style of the listview.  However in my case, the clicking event is generated by the TextView underneath with onclick event attached to it.

When touch event occurs, Listview isn't aware of clicking is happening. It doesn't receive focused or pressed event.

Is there bubbling or capturing technique I could use like Flex did?  Or any suggestion/solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
View tempView = null;  // Class Variable to temporary store Clicked Row's view
```

Method:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id)
{
    listView.setFocusable(true);
    listView.setSelected(true);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); // CHANGE COLOR OF SELECTED ROW HERE>
    selectedId = (int)id;

    if(tempView != null){
        //If row is already clicked then reset its color to default row color
        tempView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
    tempView = v;
```

}

Hope this helps. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for complement. Once i under go same problem & found solution my self, Shared it with community..

Comment: Dear Piyushnp,      Thanks for your help.... I am also facing with the same problem. I am using the BaseAdapter for Inflating the Listview. Inside the Listview their are 3 widgets Textview,Edittext and Edittext these all three widgets are In one Row. When I click On any of the row some highlights(Color has to be shown on all three widgets). In order to show user that you have selected this row when he clicks on other row that previous color becomes normal and next selected row become color. I have tried above but my requirement is not satisfied.